# ckeditor figure caption can't delete without new paragraph

Tags: javascript, firefox, ckeditor

I have a problem with my ckeditor, if I add a image with caption without use before enter or other character I can't use backspace for delete character on image caption, but if I press other character from a to z I see this is put on caption. This is happened only on mozila firefox, and I see a `br` with `_moz_editor_bogus_node="TRUE"`. After press enter and add a new paragraph this `br` is removed and never see it, and more then that I can edit image caption (I can delete character from caption) after first paragraph insertion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason for what happened that is because on mozila firefox if editoru have no paragrah or div with `contenteditable="true"` he put a br start at body and you can't modify the text.

My solution was to modify plugin image2 to add this row:

```
this.wrapper.$.setAttribute("contenteditable","true");
```

on init element, line 425.

If have problem on mozila with a br who have attribute `_moz_editor_bogus_code="TRUE"` remeber you need to have 1 div or paragraph with `content_editable="true"`

Comment: This is an interesting hack. Firefox has now at least two serious bugs related to usage of `contenteditable=false`. https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1181130 and https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=911201. CKEditor uses this attribute to make sure that content inside a widget cannot be edited, but it also implements dozen other fixes and improvements for native behaviour of this attribute. So those fixes themselves can give you a feeling that the attribute isn't needed any more. On the other hand, some of them requires presence of this attribute (check keyboard navigation).

Comment: So your hack will fix the issue that you mentioned, but unfortunately will introduce different issues like broken backspace/arrow keys around images. This may lead to crashes, so I would not recommend this hack. PS. Make sure to ping Firefox guys about the issues – this should help.

Answer (score 1):

This issue (broken editability of captions) is causes by a regression in Firefox 39. See this [bug](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1181130). The change that caused it will be reverted in Firefox 40, so the feature should work again.

Comment: Thank you, but for moment i will use that hack,  after new version will come will need some time to upgrade all persons her browser but is good to know to fix it if Firefox will solve it. Thank you !